# ocr image cleansing with python opencv

Tags: python, opencv, ocr

I'm currently learning about computer vision OCR. I have an image that needs to be scan. I face a problem during the image cleansing.

I use opencv2 in python to do the things. This is the original image:

```py
image = cv2.imread(image_path)
cv2.imshow("imageWindow", image)
```

[image]

I want to cleans the above image, the number at the middle (64) is the area I wanted to scan. However, the number got cleaned as well.

```py
image[np.where((image > [0,0,105]).all(axis=2))] = [255,255,255]
cv2.imshow("imageWindow", image)
```

[image]

What should I do to correct the cleansing here? I wanted to make the screen where the number 64 located is cleansed coz I will perform OCR scan afterwards.

Please help, thank you in advance.

Comment: The location of that screen which is including the number is always same or varying?

Comment: it is always the same. there are a lot of images and but all of them are image of the same device. the difference is only the numbers

Comment: Then you can easily delete by using the coordinates of that rectangle part

Comment: I'm not sure whether the coordinates between all of the images are the same. the images were taken via phone, so the positioning often varies. do you have some advice for this?

Comment: ah sorry, so you were asked about the location of the screen. my bad. yes sometimes it's varies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do is called "thresholding". Looks like your technique is recoloring pixels that fall below a certain threshold, but the LCD digit darkness varies enough in that image to throw it off.

I'd spend some time reading about thresholding, here's a good starting place:
[Thresholding in OpenCV with Python](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html). You're probably going to need an adaptive technique (like Adaptive Gaussian Thresholding), but you may find other ways that work for your images.